# OpenSSL error - RestClient Gem - Python WSGI

Tags: python, ruby, ssl, wsgi, rest-client

### Issue :

I'm struggling on a SSL issue. I'm trying to connect to a Web server for a Python application but each time I execute a request, I have this error :

```
RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed:
```

### Details :

- I use the [RestClient gem (v1.8.0)](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/tree/v1.8.0) and am trying a simple GET request
- The [python code to launch the server](https://github.com/aabde/sync-engine/blob/develop/abde/bin/inbox-api#L74) is as so :

  http_server = WSGIServer(('', int(port)), app, log=nylas_logger,
                                       handler_class=NylasWSGIHandler,
                                       keyfile='/vagrant/server.key', certfile='/vagrant/server.crt')
- I use the same certificates (wildcard certificate COMODO) on another subdomain on another server (Nginx Passenger) and I can successfully launch my requests

### What I tried :

- I tried reinstalling Openssl using Brew
- I successfully launched my request passing the verify_ssl: false flag to the restclient gem (but I want to find a solution that does not use this workaround)
- I tried reinstalling Ruby (I'm using RVM) with the --disable-bynary flag
- I launched `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`

The most surprising is that I actually can perform requests on another type of server using the same certificates so it seems the issue may be with the Python web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the gevent.pywsgi server did not handle the SSL certificate correctly.
I installed Nginx and did a reverse proxy on the localhost Python gevent.pywsgi server and did the SSL handling on the Nginx part and it worked instantly.

For information, my nginx conf :

```
server{
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server{
        listen 443;
        server_name subdomain.domain.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proro $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;

            proxy_redirect http://localhost:5555 https://subdomain.domain.com;
        }
}
```

And I restricted the python server to listen only to localhost requests.